# Linq to SQL - Initialize database

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

In Entity Framework you can define a method to be called to initialize data in a database using [System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

How can you do something similar using Linq to SQL (or perhaps its better to just throw something in Application_Start?)

Answer (score 0):

The SetInitializer is used with Entity Framework CodeFirst, there is no equivalent for Linq to SQL.  However, you could always create and run some sql commands via ADO.NET if you really wanted too.  But it might be easier to just create a database script and run it against the database.

Comment: Or even better - read the DBML file and make your SQL from that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not nearly as robust as Entity Framework, but the DataContext generated by SqlMetal or via the designer allows you to do something like this:

```
var db = new MyDataContext();
if (!db.DatabaseExists()) {
    db.CreateDatabase();
}
db.ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, etc. etc.) VALUES (1, etc. etc.)")
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase.aspx) for more information.